# Equivalent in Html of : <jsp:forward page="/UserController?action=listUser" /> ??

Tags: html, jsp, action, forward

Which is the equivalent  in Html of this: 
`<jsp:forward page="/UserController?action=listUser" />`    ?? 
Thank you!!

Comment: I'd say `window.location.href="/UserController?action=listUser"` (of course in JavaScript) but remember it's not exactly the same because, without server side code, client will first download and parse page (but you can put it on very first beginning) and then forward to another one. This will change SE behavior and affect browsing history too.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but it doesn't work...I have problems with UserController... maybe the problem is the path...